# Timestamp based folder creation in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a timestamp based folder structure. If I pass the timestamp then it reads the folder structure according to the input path. Similarly, I need to create a timestamp based folder structure to write a output path.

```
This is my input path 
/Desktop/user/outFiles6/test1/2017/06/09/15

Similarly my output path should be created.
```

I tried like this

```
  def buildPaths(date_key: DateTime, sc:SparkContext): (Path,Path) = {
  val (year, month, day,hour) = (date_key.toString("YYYY"), date_key.toString("MM"), date_key.toString("dd"),date_key.toString("HH"))
  val inpath_tag = new Path(
    makePath("/", Some("") :: Some("/home/user/Desktop/SparK-op/") :: Some(year) :: Some(month) :: Some(day) :: Some(hour) :: Nil)
  )

  val outpath = new Path(
    makePath("/", Some("") :: Some("/home/user/Desktop/SparK-op/") :: Some(year) :: Some(month) :: Some(day) ::  Some(hour) :: Nil)
  )
  //queryHDFS(sc, inpath_tag);
  //queryHDFS(sc, inpath_sens);
  (inpath_tag, outpath)
   }
  def makePath(char:String, components: List[Option[String]]) = components.flatten mkString char;

  } 
  }
```

I don't know how to proceed.any help to construct a logic would be appreciated.

Comment: What is exactly the problem you're having? And where does `Path` come from? E.g. if it is `java.nio.file.Path`, it cannot be created with `new` and you should use `Paths.get`.

Comment: Its hadoop path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to import the library `File` for it to work. Basically it is needed to create your directory and also for checking if any directory is already present. Below is the code to create directory recursively.

```
import java.io.File

def makePath(char:String, components: List[Option[String]]) = {
   var path = ""
   var pathstring = components.flatten mkString char
   var pathArray = pathstring.split("/")
   for (directory <- pathArray) {
         if( directory != ""){
             path += directory 
             //Check if path present else create
             var file = new File(path)
             if(!file.exists){
                file.mkdir
                path += "/" // separator for creating next directory
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use Spark SQL's Dataset/DataFrame and not bound strictly to how exactly you output folder structure looks like. If so, you can simply use standard Spark/Hive way of doing partitioning like that

```
  df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").format("parquet").save(outPath)
```

Yoy will have your output files in files under *outPath/year=2017/month=12/day=10*.