# Spark - Stream kafka to file that changes every day?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a kafka stream I will be processing in spark.  I want to write the output of this stream to a file.  However, I want to partition these files by day, so everyday it will start writing to a new file.  Can something like this be done?  I want this to be left running and when a new day occurs, it will switch to write to a new file.

```
val streamInputDf = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrapservers", "XXXX")
                    .option("subscribe", "XXXX")
                    .load()
val streamSelectDf = streamInputDf.select(...)

streamSelectDf.writeStream.format("parquet)
     .option("path", "xxx")
     ???
```

Comment: Why not consume the data from Kafka directly into Spark?

Comment: Because for auditing purposes, we must run this dataflow like every other dataflow we have(daily at a set time).  So all I have to do is land the data which will be processed later.  @RobinMoffatt.  I thought about doing `writeStream` with `.trigger(ProcessingTime("24 hours"))` but I don't know how I would get the file being written to, to actually change

Comment: You mention Kafka, but in fact Kafka it self should just act as a message bus. If you are using a Cloudera/Hortonworks Data Flow platform you have NiFi to move data to/from Kafka, otherwise you can use a tool like Spark or Kafka Connect to fill this role.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Correct. Sorry, I forgot to mention.  I will be using spark to process this data to a file.  However I am unsure how to partition the messages by date so when a new day occurs files are put into a new file (small edit to original post)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079832/timestamp-based-folder-creation-in-scala-spark) spark should be able to write to a folder based on the year, month and day, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for. Have not tried it in spark streaming, but hopefully this example gets you on the right track:

```
df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").format("parquet").save(outPath)
```

If not, you might be able to put in a variable filepath based on `current_date()`

Answer (score 1):

> Adding partition from spark can be done with `partitionBy` provided in
>   `DataFrameWriter` for non-streamed or with [`DataStreamWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.html) for
>   streamed data.

---

Below are the signatures :

> public DataFrameWriter partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq
>   colNames)
>
> DataStreamWriter   partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq colNames)
>   Partitions the output by the given columns on the file system.
>
> DataStreamWriter partitionBy(String... colNames) Partitions the
>   output by the given columns on the file system.
>
> Description : 
>   partitionBy public DataStreamWriter partitionBy(String... colNames)
>   Partitions the output by the given columns on the file system. If
>   specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to Hive's
>   partitioning scheme. As an example, when we partition a dataset by
>   year and then month, the directory layout would look like:
>
> ```
>  
> - year=2016/month=01/ 
> - year=2016/month=02/
> ```
>
> Partitioning is one of the most widely used techniques to optimize
>   physical data layout. It provides a coarse-grained index for skipping
>   unnecessary data reads when queries have predicates on the partitioned
>   columns. In order for partitioning to work well, the number of
>   distinct values in each column should typically be less than tens of
>   thousands.
>
> Parameters: colNames - (undocumented) Returns: (undocumented) Since:
>   2.0.0

so if you want to partition data by year and month spark will save the data to folder like:

```
year=2019/month=01/05
year=2019/month=02/05
```

***Option 1*** (Direct write):
You have mentioned parquet - you can use saving as a parquet format with:

```
df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month','day').format("parquet").save(path)
```

***Option 2*** (insert in to hive using same `partitionBy` ):

You can also insert into hive table like:

```
df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day').insertInto(String tableName)
```

***Getting all hive partitions:***

Spark sql is based on hive query language so you can use `SHOW PARTITIONS`

To get list of partitions in the specific table.

```
sparkSession.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS partitionedHiveParquetTable")
```

Conclusion : 
I would suggest option 2 ... since Advantage is later you can query data based on partition (aka query on raw data to know what you have received) and underlying file can be parquet or orc.

***Note :***

Just make sure you have `.enableHiveSupport()` when you are creating session with `SparkSessionBuilder` and also make sure whether you have `hive-conf.xml` etc. configured properly.

Comment: if you are okay with answer please accept as owner!